# Google script to duplicate sheet with values and format only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Help pls. I need simple script that can duplicate the sheet with values (not formulas) and formatting
Then I will assign this script to the button, I can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to duplicate a sheet in a Google Spreadsheet with the cell format and values.
- When the sheet is duplicated, you want to copy only values without including the formulas.

In this case, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Duplicate a sheet using `duplicateActiveSheet()` of Class Spreadsheet or `copyTo` of Class Sheet.
2. Copy the values without including the formulas in the copied sheet using `copyTo` of Class Range.

#### Sample script:

When you want to duplicate the active sheet, that the button is putting, and you are not required to rename the copied sheet, it becomes as follows. When you assign `myFunction` to the button on Google Spreadsheet, you can run the script by clicking it.

```
function myFunction() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

#### Note:

- When you want to give the source sheet name and the copied sheet name, you can also use the following script. Before you use this, please set the variables of `sourceSheetName` and `copiedSheetName`.

  ```
    function myFunction2() {
      const sourceSheetName = "Sheet1";
      const copiedSheetName = "CopiedSheet1";

      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const range = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName).copyTo(ss).setName(copiedSheetName).getDataRange();
      range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly:true});
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [duplicateActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#duplicateactivesheet)
- [copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [copyTo(destination, options) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

### Added

From your replying of `unfortunately, your script doesnt copy format ( only values`, I added the following script.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  range.copyTo(range, {formatOnly: true});  // Added
  range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, your script doesnt copy format ( only values

Comment: @Max Ambinder Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I thought that "format" you are thinking might be different from my understanding. So I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expected, I apologize again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function duplicate() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Source Sheet/Target Sheet/range in A1Notation","src/tgt/A1" , SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(resp.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
     let t=resp.getResponseText().split('/');
     let src=ss.getSheetByName(t[0]);
     let tgt=ss.getSheetByName(t[1]);
     let srcrg=src.getRange(t[2]);
     let srcvs=srcrg.getDisplayValues();
     let tgtrg=tgt.getRange(t[2]);
     srcrg.copyTo(tgtrg,{formatOnly:true});//copy format
     tgtrg.setValues(srcvs);//copy display values
  }
}
```