# Script to duplicate the current sheet instead of creating a new sheet in a workbook in Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script and it works the way I want it to.  However, instead of making a new sheet, I'd like it to duplicate the main sheet (called TODAY) and insert the information as the script already does.

What do I need to change to get this to do that?

Thanks in advance!

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuItems=[{name:"Move Entries",functionName:"moveToTab"}];
  ss.addMenu("Script",menuItems);
};

function moveToTab() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = [];
  ss.getSheets().forEach(function(sheet){sheets[sheet.getName()]=sheet;});
  //Logger.log(sheets['TODAY'].getName());
  
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('TODAY');
  var r = s.getDataRange();
  var v = r.getDisplayValues();
  var dates = s.getRange('A2:A').getDisplayValues().map(function(item){return item[0].slice(0,10);}).flat();
  var uniqueDates = dates.filter( function(v, i, a) { return v!=='' && a.indexOf(v) === i; } );
  //Logger.log(uniqueDates);
  
  //Logger.log( v[1][0].slice(0,10) );
  for(var i=0;i<uniqueDates.length;i++) {
    var date = uniqueDates[i];
    if(!sheets[date]) {
      var newSheet = ss.insertSheet(date);
      sheets[date] = newSheet;
      newSheet.appendRow(v[0]);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
    //var ns = ss.getSheetByName( sheets[date] );
    var ns = sheets[date];
    var nv = v.filter(function(rows){return rows[0].slice(0,10)===date});
    if(nv.length) {
      ns.getRange(ns.getLastRow()+1,1,nv.length,nv[0].length).setValues(nv);
    }
  }
  
  s.insertRowBefore(2);
  if(s.getMaxRows()>2)
    s.deleteRows(3,s.getMaxRows()-2);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};
```

I've tried using duplicateActiveSheet command, but it comes back with a string error.

Comment: Have you tried using the [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)) method with what you'd like to accomplish?

Comment: Your script currently creates x no. of new sheets if the no. of records in A column after the header are x. Each of those new sheets contains the same header with one record depending the index. I didn't completely understand the ask here.
Do you want the new sheets to contain exactly the same data as the main sheet TODAY?

Comment: The new sheet that it creates has no formatting, so I want to apply the same formatting from TODAY to the new sheet. 

Basically it creates a new sheet based on the date in column A. The TODAY sheet is formatted from a Google form so the column headers are formatted and there's a frozen column C so you can scroll the rest of the column's information horizontally.

Comment: Related question: [Google script to duplicate sheet with values and format only [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65502593/1330560). Though closed there are two answers and both use the `range.copyTo` with the `{formatOnly:true}` setting. Does this meet your needs?

Comment: I'm unsure of how to add this into my script. I think what might help is if I make a blank sheet set up the way I want it to look. Have the script duplicate that sheet and add the information in as the script already does.